# Find the maximum flow f, in which f(e) is the maximum flow possible in a given edge e

Tags: algorithm, graph

> Given a flow network, G(V,E), a source s, a sink t and a capacity function c: E --> R U {0}. Also, given an edge e=(u,v) in E. I need to find an efficient algorithm to find among all the maximum flows from s to t, a maximum flow f in the network, in which f(e) is the maximum flow possible in the edge e.

Please solve the problem and explain why the algorithm works correctly.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please read: [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly you need Ford-Fulkerson algorithm to solve standard maximum flow problem. Basically it works like this:

**1. Assign 0 flow to every edge.**

**2. Build a residual network (of useful edges).**

**3. Find any path satisfying your requirements.**

**4. Update network. Is there any way that you can have more flow? If not, stop, else go to point 2.**